# How do you apply a format in pandas to an exported excel file (specifically trying to fill blank cells)

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to construct code that will extract data from on dataframe, apply specific headers and remove redundant ones, following this using the data that is to be placed under the headings I need to fill in the blanks with a solid color in order to highlight them for analysis and then export them to a new excel file in order to disseminate it.

Ive tried the apply color, ive defined the color and ive tried formating in CSS, the probelm is that the while the format seems to be applied in the IDE it is not translating into the exported Excel file.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.formats.style import Styler
import xlsxwriter
from io import BytesIO
from flask import Flask, send_file
emt = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\okelly\Python Project\excel input file.xlsx', header=[0,1])# this adds the parameter into the heading allowing a search of it

#this part works
M_cols = [col for col in emt.columns if 'M' in col]
#this identifies all colums wiht M in thier subheading which is a mandoatory heading and seperates it from three other classes of headings

new_data=pd.DataFrame(emt, columns=M_cols)
#this command pulls the data and sets the list m-cols as the headers 

#this code hopefully applies a highlight to hte code in order to allow it to be anaslied
def highlight_null(val):
 if val == 'none':
      color = 'yellow'
  else : color = 'white'
 return 'background-color: %s' % color

result.style.apply(highlight_null)



result.to_excel('output1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
```

no errors seem to come up, and it does produce the excel file but there is no formatting to the file

Comment: i don't think pandas does formatting in excel. Try openpyxl or something for that

Comment: what is `result` here?

Comment: result is the exported file, I have tried openpyxl and I cant get the new dataframe produced with it hence the reliance on panda

Comment: from your code i didnot see where you exported the file before that line, however from what I got I have posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand:
Assuming the dataframe is like :

```
df=pd.util.testing.makeMissingDataframe(density=0.5).head().reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns=['M1','A','B','M2']
print(df)
```

---

```
         M1         A         B        M2
0 -0.877957       NaN -2.374154 -0.585370
1       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2       NaN  0.272616  0.011746 -0.344501
3       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
4  1.478556       NaN       NaN -0.685351
```

---

You can try with the below func:

```
M_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'M' in col]
#['M1', 'M2']
def myfunc(x):
    c1='background-color: red'
    c2=''
    d_f= pd.DataFrame(np.where(x.isnull(),c1,c2),columns=x.columns,index=x.index)
    return d_f
df.style.apply(myfunc, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, M_cols],axis=None)#.to_excel(...)
```

---

Output:

[image]